# Replace values of an R data.frame between certain Dates?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, tidyverse, lubridate

I have the following `data.frame` and would like to `replace` values of `Flow` to -1 for the  year 2001. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), to = as.Date("2005-12-31"), by = "day"),
                       Flow = runif(1826,1,5))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the `year` from 'Date' column, check if it is equal to 2001, and replace with `-1`

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
DF <- DF %>% 
   mutate(Flow = replace(Flow, year(Date) == 2001, -1))
```

---

Or using `base R` - get the 'Year' part by standard use of `format` and do the check with '2001' to create a logical vector and assign those 'Flow' elements to -1

```
DF$Flow[format(DF$Date, '%Y') %in% '2001'] <- -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R option -

Use `grepl`/`grep` to find the rows which start with 2001, and change the `Flow` values to -1.

```
DF$Flow[grep('^2001', DF$Date)] <- -1
DF
```